# redhat developers edition does not allow to download package

Tags: repository, redhat

I have downloaded redhat developers edition for linux and installed it in vmware.
this is ok and working - I can login after boot
I did the registration as requested. status registered
but when doing : list
status=not subscribed
register..  already registered
The question would be : can I download additional packages as telnet... and how to subscribe to be able to download packages[subs status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzAab.png) ?
how to create a repo with this subscription ?
thanks for all feedback/help
Best Regards, Guy Przytula

Comment: according the doc : after first boot you should accept license - I did not get this screen nor prompt - using subscription in gui - indicates CA certificate not installed - where can we get this for the free/developer edition

Comment: Could you please specify more clearly what errors you're seeing at what point? Or perhaps just format your question better, so that it's possible to distinguish command output from your writing.